# Vector Scaling of Object Positions

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question in regards to scaling a position based on the scale of a shape. So initially lets say that we have a point at the very top of a object and we change the scale of the shape by 50% or any amount how would one scale the point to be at the top of the now scaled object.

Comment: What about scaling the point in the same way as you scale the object? It will remain on the same position.

Comment: The way of scaling the object is not accessible.

Comment: Can you please modify your question and be more specific about the precise problem setup then? To me, it is not clear what is being asked.